# How to get a <ul> with bullets to align nicely next to a floating image?

Tags: css, layout, html-lists, css-float, image

I have an image floated to the left of a containing div.

I then have a  which I would like to align next to the image.

My problem is that the bullets (which are BG images) are not clearing the image.

I hope the image below illustrates my problem:

---

[image]

---

My HTML:

```
<div id="project-detail">
        <img src="/assets/images/our-work/hartford-444x444.jpg" alt="Hartford Homes" />
        <h2>Project Detail Heading here H2</h2>
        <p>Work intro text will go in here text dolor sit amet, consectetur adip isicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudan tium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae.</p>
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudan tium, totam rem <a href="#" title="Link Title">this is a link</a> aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae.</p>
        <p>Voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudan tium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae.</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Ut enim ad minima exercit. veniam, quis.</li>
            <li>Ut enim ad minima exercit. veniam, quis.</li>
            <li>Ut enim ad minima exercit. veniam, quis.</li>
            <li>Ut enim ad minima exercit. veniam, quis.</li>
            <li>Ut enim ad minima exercit. veniam, quis.</li>
            <li>Ut enim ad minima exercit. veniam, quis.</li>
            <li>Ut enim ad minima exercit. veniam, quis.</li>
            <li>Ut enim ad minima exercit. veniam, quis.</li>
            <li>Ut enim ad minima exercit. veniam, quis.</li>
            <li>Ut enim ad minima exercit. veniam, quis.</li>
            <li>Ut enim ad minima exercit. veniam, quis.</li>
            <li>Ut enim ad minima exercit. veniam, quis.</li>
            <li>Ut enim ad minima exercit. veniam, quis.</li>
            <li>Ut enim ad minima exercit. veniam, quis.</li>
            <li>Ut enim ad minima exercit. veniam, quis.</li>
            <li>Ut enim ad minima exercit. veniam, quis.</li>
            <li>Ut enim ad minima exercit. veniam, quis.</li>
            <li>Ut enim ad minima exercit. veniam, quis.</li>
            <li>Ut enim ad minima exercit. veniam, quis.</li>
            <li>Ut enim ad minima exercit. veniam, quis.</li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- end #project-detail -->
```

---

and my CSS:

```
 #project-detail {
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    width:940px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}

#project-detail img {
    float:left;
    margin:0 20px 20px 0;
    border:8px solid #eee; 
    background:#eee;
    /* CSS3 border radius */
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
}

#project-detail h2 {

}

#project-detail ul {
    list-style:none;
    line-height:1.6;
}

#project-detail ul li {
    padding-left:16px;
    background:url(/assets/images/li-bg.gif) top left no-repeat;
}
```

---

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated! :o)

**NB: If possible I want to try and find a solution without seperating the image and the text into two different divs (one left and one right). THis is because I would like the containing div to be wysiwyg controlled, so it needs to be able to handle anything in it really. There may be an image there, there may not be. I HOPE THIS MAKES SENSE**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few possible CSS-only solutions.

1. Add the `overflow: hidden` to the `#project-detail ul li`, doing so you'll make the list items to be properly aligned near the floated image.
2. Use the `list-style-image` (and `list-style-position: inside` if needed), so the bullet would be positioned near the content and not in the background.
3. Use the `:before` pseudo-element, positioning it how you need, so it won't go under the floated image.

Answer (score 1):

separate your list from the image, into their own `div` and position the `div's` appropriately.

Comment: That would be the ideal solution, but unfortunately I'm trying to set it up so the containing div is wysiwyg and people can enter in what ever they want. There may be an image there, there may not be. Hmm...

Comment: I can't see how your requirements prevent you from dividing content with a [div](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Div) even if it means nesting which is admittedly is nice to avoid